# Gradle 6.8 to 7 migration dependency configuration issue

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to upgrade from 6.8 to 7. The project started on gradle 4.x and the dependencies are configured as compile and runtime.
I started by changing all compile to implementation but found the following issue:
when updating,
`compile (group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: AWS_JAVA_SDK_VERSION)` 
to
`implementation (group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: AWS_JAVA_SDK_VERSION)`

but then on a child project, I see a compilation error, which is not present when using compile

```
S3StorageController.java:3: error: package com.amazonaws.regions does not exist
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
```

How can I define the dependency so that is is available on other projects?

Comment: Are you by chance using the `java-library` plugin?

Comment: no, am not, the java plugin

Comment: You need to show a bit more content from the `build.gradle`, especially the parent/child relationship. Otherwise, it is hard to reason about potential causes.

Comment: Please help me here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73301984/react-native-gradle-7-migration-trouble-in-migrating-to-gradle-7-for-the-e

Comment: I am having the similar Gradle 7 migration issue and completely blocked in it.