# React Native | Gradle 7 | Migration - Trouble in migrating to Gradle 7 for the existing react native project

Tags: react-native, expo, migration, npm-package, android-gradle-7.0

I am having some issues when migrating to Gradle 7 and I got a few errors at the runtime. My build is getting successful but cannot be redirected to the **”Login Screen”**. As such, the issue is basically raised from the NPM package that creates an issue while migrating.

**Java Version:**

```
JDK Version: 11
```

**Android Versions:**

```
Gradle Version: 7.2
Gradle Plugin Version: 4.2.2

buildToolsVersion = '30.0.2'
supportLibVersion = '30.0.2'

minSdkVersion = 26
compileSdkVersion = 31
targetSdkVersion = 30

kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
```

**React Native Versions:**

```
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",

"react-native": "0.68.0",
"react-native-flipper": "^0.153.0",

"react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.4",

"expo": "^44.0.0",
```

**Root cause of the issue:**

- I am using some npm libraries that are deprecated, For e.g. I am using `unimodules` that are now deprecated and of no use, so instead I used `expo` modules, and currently the expo version `44.0.0`.
- Below are URLs from which I migrated `react-native-unimodules` to `expo`, these are the URLs helpful to migrate to the `expo` modules.

  - https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules
  - https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/expo-modules-migration.md
- The `expo` modules create some issues at the runtime and throw the error mentioned in the screenshot at the bottom.

**Error message:**

> ERROR  TypeError: (0, _expoModulesCore.requireNativeModule) is not a
> function. (In '(0,
> _expoModulesCore.requireNativeModule)('ExpoCrypto')', '(0, _expoModulesCore.requireNativeModule)' is undefined)  LOG  Running "TestApp" with {"rootTag":1}  ERROR  Invariant Violation:
> "TestApp" has not been registered. This can happen if:
>
> - Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
> - A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

**Note:**

- I have gone through many documents and URLs for a better understanding and applied a few steps as per the requirements.
- But there are no specific steps that are given anywhere to migrate to Gradle 7, not even in the React Native or Facebook community’s forum page.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Expo Package Error]

Comment: Any suggestions or queries?